# onBackPressed() not working inside ActivityGroup

Tags: android, activitygroup

I have an `ActivityGroup` inside of which I have an Activity. I have `overrided` the `onBackPressed()` in this Activity. But unfortunately my `onBackPressed()` is not being called. So I tried with `onKeyDown()`. But no effect at all. My problem is, the `onBackPressed()` event which I have given in the `ActivityGroup` takes control. How to override the Back Press event inside my sub Activity?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866528/android-onkeydown-problem/5869751#5869751

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had this same problem and I solved it by calling the current activity's onBackPressed from the ActivityGroup:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    int length = idList.size();
    if (length > 1)
    {
        Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(
            idList.get(length - 1));
        current.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

idList is a list of activities in the activity group.

Comment: Actually I have used MediaPlayer in my activity. I tried as you have suggested and now I ma able to call my onBackPressed() of my current activity in which I have stopped my MediaPlayer. But still the won't stop playing after returning to my ActivityGroup.

Comment: Can you detail how you maintain the list of IDs? It seems natural to just call getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity() but that seems to return null.

Comment: What if you don't want the current activity?  I'm using the ActivityGroup to manage a chain of groups. If I have activities A, B, C, D, am currently on activity D and want to go back to B.  I have to be able to specify activity B to the .destroyActivity command in LocalActivityManager.  The list that I maintain provides this.

Comment: @ArpitGarg If you are going to mark the answer down, could you at least explain why it didn't work, or give an appropriate solution?

Comment: @MattBecker I used to call the current activity's onBackPressed from the ActivityGroup: But nothing the problem is same no back press on ActivityGroup was enabled as you said in the post

Comment: @ArpitGarg I dunno buddy.  I works for me in production code and for the OP.  I guess you'll have to work it out yourself.