# Switching between tab using activity group it want to display last activity - Tab ActivityGroup

Tags: android, tabs

I have written tab for my android application.

My question is switching between tab using activity group it want to display last activity. I want to show last open/visited screen when we navigate the tab.My one is go to first screen:

I need to show last opened screen when navigate through Tab

Tab 1 -> Sales. This  contain 10 screen inside (actiivity)
Tab 2 -> Admin .This contain 5 screen inside (actiivity)
Tab 3 -> Setting.This contain 8 screen inside. (actiivity)

**I clicked Tab 1 , it load tab 1's screen which is contain list of sales route .then I clicked one sales route , it goes to list of retailer in the first tab.Then I cliched tab 3  "Setting " finish some work & come back to sales, That time it should show last open screen in the "sales" tab.**

**When I clicked tab, It should show last open activity** How to do?

I did like this.Please indicate where I want to change the code for my requirements.

MainActivity.It will call after login

```
  public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
int selectedTab;
TabHost tabHost ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabview);

    TabHost t = getTabHost();
    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
    /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Sales").setContent(new Intent(this,SalesActivityGroup.class));
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Admin").setContent(new Intent(this,SettingActivityGroup.class));
    thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Setting").setContent(new Intent(this,SettingActivityGroup.class));


    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    tabHost.setMinimumHeight(25);
}

public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
        selectedTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

First Tab1(Sales)'s SalesGroupActivity

```
 public class SalesActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

public static SalesActivityGroup group;
private ArrayList<View> history;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
    group = this;

    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Sales",
            new Intent(this, SalesRouteActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();

    replaceView(view);

}

public void replaceView(View v) {
    history.add(v);
    setContentView(v);

}

public void back() {
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        history.remove(history.size() - 1);
        if (history.size() > 0) {
            setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SalesActivityGroup.group.back();
    return;
}
```

**Edited** 
This is FirstTab's firstActivity - SalesRouteActivity

```
    public class SalesRouteActivity extends ListActivity{
     TableLayout tl;
     static int positions = 0;
     static String keyword ="";
     int uploadSize = 0;
     private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
     private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
     String strBusinessUnit = "";   
     String strExecutive = "";
     String strTerritoryCode = "";
     SimpleAdapter sd;
     View row = null;
     View selectRow = null;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.sales_routes);

         SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myLogedPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
         strBusinessUnit = myPrefs.getString("BusinessUnit", "");
         strExecutive = myPrefs.getString("Executive", "");
         strTerritoryCode = myPrefs.getString("TerritoryCode", "");

         ArrayList<SalesRoutes> routeList = getSalesRoute();

         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> routhPath = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size(); i++) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(routeList.get(i).getOutlets()) >0){
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("routeCode",((SalesRoutes) routeList.get(i)).getRouteCode());
                map.put("routeName",((SalesRoutes) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
                map.put("outlets", ((SalesRoutes) routeList.get(i)).getOutlets());
                routhPath.add(map);
             }
         }

         ListView list = getListView();
         sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, routhPath, R.layout.route_path,new String[] {"routeCode","routeName","outlets" },new int[] { R.id.routeCode,R.id.routeName,R.id.outlets});
         row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.route_path_row, null, false);
         getListView().addHeaderView(row);
         list.setAdapter(sd);
         list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        list.setSelected(true);
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        list.setItemChecked(positions, true);
        list.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();

        if (routeList.size() > 0) {
            keyword = routeList.get(0).getRouteCode();
        }

        uploadSize = new UploadActivity().getUploadTable();

        if (uploadSize > 0) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "New Alert, Click Me!",System.currentTimeMillis());
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence contentTitle = "Upload Available...";
            CharSequence contentText = "Browse Android Official Site by clicking me";
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SalesRouteActivity.this, 0, notifyIntent,android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle,contentText, intent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        keyword = hashMap.get("routeCode");

        positions = position;
        if(position == 0 ){


        }else if(position != 1){
            Intent showContent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SalesRouteDevitionActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("RouteCode", keyword);
            showContent.putExtras(bundle);
            getParent().startActivityForResult(showContent, 5);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(SalesRouteActivity.this, ListRetailerActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("RouteName", keyword);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            View view = SalesActivityGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();  
            SalesActivityGroup.group.replaceView(view);

        }
    }

    @Override  
    public void onBackPressed() {  
        SalesActivityGroup.group.back();  
    } 

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public ArrayList<SalesRoutes> getSalesRoute(){
         DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
          try {
              dbAdapter.createDataBase();
         } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
         }
         dbAdapter.openDataBase();       
         String sql = "SELECT RouteCode, Description, OutletsAttached  " +
                       "FROM WMRoute  " +
                       "WHERE ActiveStatus = '1' AND  RouteDefaultExecutive = ? AND  BusinessUnit = ? AND TerritoryCode = ?  " +
                       "ORDER BY RouteCode  ";

         String[]d = new String[]{strExecutive,strBusinessUnit,strTerritoryCode};
         ArrayList stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(sql, d);
         dbAdapter.close();
         ArrayList<SalesRoutes> salesRoutesList = new ArrayList<SalesRoutes>();
         for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Object> arrayList = (ArrayList<Object>) stringList.get(i);
            ArrayList<Object> list = arrayList;
            SalesRoutes salesRoutes = new SalesRoutes();
            try {
                salesRoutes.setRouteCode((String) list.get(0));
                salesRoutes.setDescription((String) list.get(1));
                salesRoutes.setOutlets((String)list.get(2));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("***" + SalesRouteActivity.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            }
            salesRoutesList.add(salesRoutes);
        }
        return salesRoutesList;
    }
}
```

**probably my ActivityGroups are being created again and again when you switch between tabs
So   groups want to create only once and resumed when i switch between tabs**

Every screen details/contents getting from database..

I am facing this issue more than 2 days....Please help me. 
Please help me on this....

Thanks  in advance.....

Comment: Hey I have updated & mention everything in question....

Comment: @Nagkeeran Piraba can you come in Casual Chat room so that I have help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Why **onTabChanged()** method is required there?  Where you are using **int selectedTab**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks All;

There were issue in my MainActivity.

```
 tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SalesActivityGroup.class);  
    spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("Sales").setIndicator("Sales",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingActivityGroup.class);  
    spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("Admin").setIndicator("Admin",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.admin)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingActivityGroup.class);  
    spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("Setting").setIndicator("Setting",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingActivityGroup.class);  
    spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("Inquiry").setIndicator("Inquiry",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    tabHost.setMinimumHeight(18);
    tabHost.setFadingEdgeLength(5);
    tabHost.setFocusable(true); 
    tabHost.requestFocus();
    tabHost.setFadingEdgeLength(5);
  }
}
```

And I agree @Vaibhav Jani @Dharmendra @Suri, I missed that onKeyPressed() in all Activity.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to override `onBackPressed()` inside activities which you are opening in `activity-group`

Write a code below in **each activity** which you are opening in activity-group

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed() {  
       SalesActivityGroup.group.back();  
}
```

And also replace the `onBackPressed()` with following code in **`TABHOST`**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Best of luck

Comment: This method need to write where SalesGroupActivity or MainActivity? `@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
`

Answer (score 4):

The activity groups you created will hold your current activity view will not change unless you change it, Therefore while you are navigating between tabs the activity groups you have assigned to those tabs will not change their views will remain as it is.

**You can try this ....**

**For each of your activity** you must override `onBackPressed()` ...

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed() {  
       ActivityGroupRelatedToThisActivity.group.back();  
}
```

Also remember **do not call** `super.onBackPressed()` in any of your Activity which is related to activity group

**Or**

Change `private ArrayList<View> history` to `static private ArrayList<View> history`

and

```
if(history.size() == 0) replaceView(view);
```

in `ActivityGroup`'s `onCreate()` method

Comment: Hi!! Calling Activity I should call Like this `@Override protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
 if(position != 1){
Intent showContent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SalesRouteDevitionActivity.class);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("RouteCode", keyword);
  showContent.putExtras(bundle);   getParent().startActivityForResult(showContent, 5); } }` & overrite  `onBackPressed()` is it?

Comment: Please post your this code in question(then it will be more readable will also help us to understand your problem), And yes you have to override onBackPressed() in each activity which is in Activity group

Comment: Updated my code above.Please look at that .. Could you please come to chat for a while regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be help you. I have used the group activity for my tabs. Let me know if you still find the problem

[Why Back button is not detecting in muti tab activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368012/why-back-button-is-not-detecting-in-muti-tab-activities)

Comment: No.This is not helpful for me.Please tell me what is an issue in my code? What i want to correct.Only that problem otherwise working fine.

Comment: You must debug your code in detail. Check out the view ArrayList<View> history size() , check out if the onCreate() is calling or not. Check out the back() method is debugger.
As the code is looking fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having a problem in back() of ActivityGroup, please try this.

```
public void back()
{
    if ( history.size() > 1 )
    {
       history.remove(history.size() - 1);
       View v = arrList.get(history.size() - 1);
       setContentView(v);
    }
    else {
       this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your update. I'm not sure how to answer your question. Perhaps you can save information about what view is currently being diplayed in `onSavedInstanceState` and fetch the data it in `onRestoreInstancestate` and use it to recreate the view. As a side note, `ActivityGroup` is deprecated, and has been replaced by the `Fragment` API.