# onTabChanged is change that time need to dispaly last open/visited activity

Tags: android

My question is switching between tab using activity group it want to display last activity. I want to show last open/visited screen when we navigate the tab.My one is go to first screen:

How can I implement this.

Please help me....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you want to use ActivityGroup here is a Example of using that.

[Example of ActivityGroup](http://androidgenuine.com/)

Comment: I have implemented this...but there are some issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936361/switching-between-tab-using-activity-group-it-want-to-display-last-activity-tab